# "Know not to do something?"

Tags: grammar

Can I use this construction to mean "Know better than to do something"?

> You know not to interrupt when someone else is talking.

=

> You know better than to interrupt when someone else is talking.

Or does the first structure not exist?

Answer (score 1):

One way of expressing this idea:

*You know that is it rude to interrupt when someone is talking.*

You can leave out words without changing the meaning this way:

*You know not to interrupt when someone is talking.*

Therefore I believe the first example sentence is acceptable, and the second example sentence is also.

"Know better" is a shorthand phrase that is understood to mean "You know you should not (do an action)..." by using the phrasing "You know better than to (do an action)."